# Changing list value inside of a json object

Tags: python, json

I find this a bit hard to explain, however.

I have a very big json object I got as a response from an API. This has about a years worth of data inside of each key. There are 3 keys `prices`, `market_cap`, `total_volume`.
Each key consists of the same; a list with `N` lists inside which store a UNIX timestamp and a price.

`N` = 24 per day (in this case my data is a years worth so 365 * 24)

Now I need to convert all of these UNIX timestamps back to readable datetime.

I want to do this for each key as each key has one large list with in there more lists which consists of a unix timestamp and another int.

I want the output to be either another dict or the same dict altered to then later use this data.

Json object

```json
{'prices': [[1581984000000, 9723.605026422496], [1582070400000, 10133.817417084678], [1582156800000, 9618.409248250406], [1582243200000, 9608.16918128246], [1582329600000, 9673.011800270346], [1582416000000, 9658.606058375473], [1582502400000, 9946.716123467522], [1582588800000, 9670.9608064677], [1582675200000, 9345.342701734848], [1582761600000, 8801.657129472504], [1582848000000, 8781.175282202359], [1582934400000, 8717.331431359424], [1583020800000, 8552.989118581636], [1583107200000, 8567.802248679225], [1583193600000, 8905.876104262194], [1583280000000, 8756.718576742549], [1583366400000, 8758.646993191916], [1583452800000, 9038.870323233425], [1583539200000, 9135.84506603321], [1583625600000, 8902.20195010789], [1583712000000, 8041.365538071835], [1583798400000, 7921.33200691072], [1583884800000, 7906.731528510632], [1583971200000, 7935.522040170545], [1584057600000, 5142.990459018316], [1584144000000, 5542.819542373153], [1584230400000, 5214.189112383918], [1584316800000, 5397.93335743919], [1584403200000, 5032.501351487721], [1584489600000, 5389.41577503409], [1584576000000, 5376.280747845438], [1584662400000, 6170.200600237675], [1584748800000, 6195.603505257629], [1584835200000, 6145.770891252399], [1584921600000, 5859.647430299388], [1585008000000, 6456.347485963419], [1585094400000, 6730.173782371188], [1585180800000, 6695.9006183977235], [1585267200000, 6765.56207892991], [1585353600000, 6397.826328325604], [1585440000000, 6255.000398693634], [1585526400000, 5915.337154791903], [1585612800000, 6403.141235565223], [1585699200000, 6421.70541388854], [1585785600000, 6640.797666310131], [1585872000000, 6807.897017890566], [1585958400000, 6732.852018394612], [1586044800000, 6859.424923721944], [1586131200000, 6788.048272605917], [1586217600000, 7297.635558289496], [1586304000000, 7196.782202442051], [1586390400000, 7342.291601148024], [1586476800000, 7294.488875121554], [1586563200000, 6864.694257006497], [1586649600000, 6878.781212589853], [1586736000000, 6913.158787469097], [1586822400000, 6857.538537511484], [1586908800000, 6860.17853570111], [1586995200000, 6629.431738031291], [1587081600000, 7059.92622475854], [1587168000000, 7035.261503989225], [1587254400000, 7242.5109294929825], [1587340800000, 7127.511949689152], [1587427200000, 6856.456278354705], [1587513600000, 6842.038597634602], [1587600000000, 7109.995291181778], [1587686400000, 7382.793144116689], [1587772800000, 7495.393587498606], [1587859200000, 7538.557687279841], [1587945600000, 7683.867415083342], [1588032000000, 7774.281554448049], [1588118400000, 7758.230255185947], [1588204800000, 8744.430287016561], [1588291200000, 8610.63580374089], [1588377600000, 8824.818413551968], [1588464000000, 8966.307014689282], [1588550400000, 8888.671912686868], [1588636800000, 8884.407813577056], [1588723200000, 9003.240557621584], [1588809600000, 9144.68703972007], [1588896000000, 9959.166416261767], [1588982400000, 9821.81131529702], [1589068800000, 9566.777187205966], [1589155200000, 8752.617087745832], [1589241600000, 8604.75159101983], [1589328000000, 8788.466749414652], [1589414400000, 9283.08601265873], [1589500800000, 9796.494527024528], [1589587200000, 9309.29535940684], [1589673600000, 9375.29710843331], [1589760000000, 9666.32719340344], [1589846400000, 9708.439858793108], [1589932800000, 9760.198937162193], [1590019200000, 9526.50759300584], [1590105600000, 9059.962506871727], [1590192000000, 9131.767275081993], [1590278400000, 9170.361063506127], [1590364800000, 8731.848525870651], [1590451200000, 8883.691769863415], [1590537600000, 8839.130663273247], [1590624000000, 9174.118563996424], [1590710400000, 9546.04563503715], [1590796800000, 9427.120373393418], [1590883200000, 9662.70587254818], [1590969600000, 9466.961781429516], [1591056000000, 10167.93069332851], [1591142400000, 9515.243858655718], [1591228800000, 9645.227869360308], [1591315200000, 9776.20299178848], [1591401600000, 9636.965527050057], [1591488000000, 9662.858709002241], [1591574400000, 9738.603356828593], [1591660800000, 9773.02951309516], [1591747200000, 9767.00531665552], [1591833600000, 9874.898681832236], [1591920000000, 9325.996856202635], [1592006400000, 9469.533297509908], [1592092800000, 9469.473456163696], [1592179200000, 9345.960907722063], [1592265600000, 9431.719262201745], [1592352000000, 9524.92661691022], [1592438400000, 9463.361414311787], [1592524800000, 9399.767217129216], [1592611200000, 9312.780104497786], [1592697600000, 9360.247968201687], [1592784000000, 9298.360829121417], [1592870400000, 9678.683208975835], [1592956800000, 9624.684291831398], [1593043200000, 9288.061774486938], [1593129600000, 9258.667161007706], [1593216000000, 9166.486360416233], [1593302400000, 9013.90556467614], [1593388800000, 9139.903276297824], [1593475200000, 9185.166540651147], [1593561600000, 9149.721996758017], [1593648000000, 9230.672998590804], [1593734400000, 9094.318072166905], [1593820800000, 9071.3850427828], [1593907200000, 9132.908369533492], [1593993600000, 9087.407312582163], [1594080000000, 9342.376492626678], [1594166400000, 9253.630980242333], [1594252800000, 9432.172515827939], [1594339200000, 9235.716302064242], [1594425600000, 9282.913638839902], [1594512000000, 9234.314674712627], [1594598400000, 9297.479635872663], [1594684800000, 9240.76251972468], [1594771200000, 9247.060695963813], [1594857600000, 9203.371435179699], [1594944000000, 9136.483376363976], [1595030400000, 9156.276583115488], [1595116800000, 9168.402736564132], [1595203200000, 9202.615839500108], [1595289600000, 9163.159654576915], [1595376000000, 9384.379751903267], [1595462400000, 9514.304987626969], [1595548800000, 9589.81771944117], [1595635200000, 9535.93879573746], [1595721600000, 9691.825138917147], [1595808000000, 9925.751397476346], [1595894400000, 10962.258481207355], [1595980800000, 10904.916526918994], [1596067200000, 11093.612240442404], [1596153600000, 11116.307163685275], [1596240000000, 11325.5515272739], [1596326400000, 11812.094307268515], [1596412800000, 11066.306240590267], [1596499200000, 11230.907762749297], [1596585600000, 11181.917508034885], [1596672000000, 11719.26352395155], [1596758400000, 11768.127742240009], [1596844800000, 11571.487980683192], [1596931200000, 11739.131006414418], [1597017600000, 11682.851469154939], [1597104000000, 11862.938012702563], [1597190400000, 11398.671060896633], [1597276800000, 11579.867951602135], [1597363200000, 11817.164038803397], [1597449600000, 11777.391322489924], [1597536000000, 11864.905810156475], [1597622400000, 11901.776488302461], [1597708800000, 12272.465808160425], [1597795200000, 11949.610970628193], [1597881600000, 11733.278970862082], [1597968000000, 11861.83657727968], [1598054400000, 11515.124298729217], [1598140800000, 11676.385305081287], [1598227200000, 11647.928120934363], [1598313600000, 11758.828120368864], [1598400000000, 11350.753473213], [1598486400000, 11465.002564032086], [1598572800000, 11300.398363810944], [1598659200000, 11519.118388160729], [1598745600000, 11481.481823317012], [1598832000000, 11701.004008657852], [1598918400000, 11672.324104943627], [1599004800000, 11895.225345345636], [1599091200000, 11418.254756916149], [1599177600000, 10197.459822768922], [1599264000000, 10484.470392265588], [1599350400000, 10177.789718049991], [1599436800000, 10260.0177277544], [1599523200000, 10359.445216989981], [1599609600000, 10125.014956069688], [1599696000000, 10230.154699360752], [1599782400000, 10342.159391205681], [1599868800000, 10378.223044584596], [1599955200000, 10439.38467226404], [1600041600000, 10328.866065987393], [1600128000000, 10661.096235144483], [1600214400000, 10787.58020807624], [1600300800000, 10952.249969107099], [1600387200000, 10937.996396960929], [1600473600000, 10927.150310293275], [1600560000000, 11083.99836119821]]}
```

*had to decrease the size of the object due to stackoverflow not allowing the amount of characters of my post, had to remove 2 keys from the object.*

My for loop to just get the lists from the key `prices`

```py
for c in obj['prices']:
    print(c)

# [1581905057626, 9860.162323271938]
# [1581908672576, 9853.961230334764]
# [1581912178268, 9803.988325218852]
# etc..
```

Now how would I go about changing the first value and then storing this all again in a new object with the same structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need new object

```
from datetime import datetime

obj = {
    'prices': [[1581984000000, 9723.605026422496],
               [1582070400000, 10133.817417084678]]
}
for c in obj['prices']:
    ts = int(c[0]/1000) # convert milisecond to second
    dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    c[0] = dt

print(obj)
```

result

```
{
  "prices": [["2020-02-18 00:00:00", 9723.605026422496], 
             ["2020-02-19 00:00:00", 10133.817417084678]]
}
```

Comment: I actually figured out something like this, ended up not being as difficult as I expected. Thanks for your answer :)